# How to accept positional argument in main parser as well as subparser?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am making a CLI that will accept Fortran code file and some functions in the following manner:-

```bash
prog -m module_name example.f only: add sub
```

How can I accept values after `only:` as separate positional arguments?

Currently `argparse` is parsing all arguments after `module_name` as Fortran files. My code is as follows.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="prog", help = "Help text)

parser.add_argument(
    "Fortran Files",
    metavar="<fortran files>",
    action="extend",  # List storage
    nargs="*",
    type=check_fortran,  # Returns a pathlib.Path
    help="""Paths to fortranfiles that will be scanned for
                   <fortran functions>.""",
)

parser.add_argument(
    "Keep functions",
    metavar="only:",
    action="extend",
    type=str,
    nargs="*",
    help="Use only fortran functions that follow.",
)

parser.add_argument(
    "-m",
    "--module",
    metavar="<modulename>",
    type=str,
    nargs=1,
    help="""Name of the module""",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any use of `subparsers`.

Use of phases like `"Keep functions"` as the `dest` is awkward and unnecessary when defining `positionals`.  They can't be used as

```
args."Keep functions"
```

Simple names like "keep" can be used as `args.keep`.

```
action="extend"
```

has no value for `positionals`.  A positional cannot be reused.  Stick with the default "store".

Using two "nargs='*'" positionals sequentially doesn't work.  The first gets all the strings, leaving none for the second.  They have to be separated by an optional like your '-m'.

I'd suggest using

```
parser.add_argument('--only', nargs='+', ....)
```

to specify the functions.  Then `args.only` will be list of function names.